Energy worldview leads to wrong conclusions on simple questions
A bamboo-copter flies up quickly into the sky, then slowly falls back to the ground. For now, we'll look at its falling process.
At the highest point, the bamboo-copter has two kinds of energy: "gravitational potential energy" and "rotational energy".
What physics tells us is that the only two things energy ever does are transfer (from one object to another) and transformation (from one kind to another). The single destination for gravitational potential energy to stop being "potential" is kinetic energy.
Assume energy is a real entity that exists in the world and also assume physics perfectly describes the behavior of energy.
Then you can easily conclude that regardless of whether there is a lift force (it needs rotational energy being consumed to keep existing and it is not a conservative force) that is opposite to direction of gravity, as long as the bamboo-copter falls the SAME distance, the SAME amount of gravitational potential energy should be converted into the SAME amount of kinetic energy. Doesn't that feel so correct?
However, nothing could be further from the truth. Except for the downward acceleration at the beginning of the descent, the bamboo-copter descends at an almost uniform speed.
So, I can't help but ask:
If you're a physics professor or something like that, do you really believe from the bottom of your heart that the energy described by physics really exists in the world or do you just use it as a mathematical tool to simplify calculations in some but not all situations?
More broadly, do people just subconsciously believe in some more primitive idea like "how much effort you put in, how much gain you get", or "if A changes one step, B will also change one step", and then use the energy in physics to endorse those original belief?
After seeing your answers and comments, I think I have to make one thing clear, that is, I am not posting this because I think energy is not conserved in this example. The question I asked has nothing to do with whether energy is conserved. (If you were to bring that up, I would say I don't know. Physics is an empirical science) Some of you seem to have missed the point.
The point you missed is that air drag is present whether the bamboo dragonfly is spinning or not and is very small for such a slender object. What is really at work here is thrust. However, thrust only exists when the bamboo dragonfly is spinning. The same rotational energy can be converted into any other energy, but this process does not necessarily produce a force in the direction opposite to gravity. For example, if the propeller section is connected to the pole section by a rusty bearing and it is placed in a vacuum chamber.
By the way, turbulent flow, acoustic energy, they are all kinetic energy of air molecules, which is transferred from the kinetic energy of the bamboo dragonfly. In other words, almost all of them comes from rotational energy. Since you believe in the law of conservation of energy, you must also believe in magic. The magic that can convert the gravitational potential energy of the bamboo dragonfly Directly into the kinetic energy of air molecules.
Later, I posted a rigorous thought experiment, definitely not opinion-based, but it was still shut down and deleted shortly after, with the reason given being that it violated their sacred law of conservation of energy. So I turned to the aviation community and asked a similar question, and the people there deleted it shortly after, saying that it should be answered by the physics community. However, I still have a chatroom in the aviation community, where there is a copy of my thought experiment and many wonderful debates, linked here.
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156078/discussion-on-question-by-american-boy-aerodynamics-experiment-questions-conserv

You forget the energy transferred to the air and other surroundings in your straw man argument against energy conservation (in turbulent flow, acoustic energy and ultimately heat). Energy conservation is one of the best tested principles of physics. Whether energy is real or a mathematical utility is of no consequence as far as physics is concerned – that's a matter of philosophy. But of course, every physical law has its range of applicability (e.g. energy isn't necessarily conserved globally in general relativity).

I assume this question will be closed - but yes, energy is a mathematical construct that helps in calculations. In your case it can not be applied in a simple way because there is interaction with the air (=friction) that must be taken into account as it "steals" some of the energy. But the bamboo-copter motion can be predicted by physics by adding this missing term. The idea about "effort and gain" is just wrong from the physics point of view. Energy is a well defined mathematical quantity that is conserved if there is no friction.

(Just to prevent a misunderstanding:Total energy (as opposed to mechanical energy) is also conserved if there is friction, it only ends up as thermal energy.)

You won't be a physics student for long if you insist on holding onto your own misinformed physical concepts.

"energy described by physics really exists in the world or do you just use it as a mathematical tool to simplify calculations?" It is a little of both. How is energy "stored in an electric field"?

"do you really believe from the bottom of your heart that the energy described by physics really exists in the world or do you just use it as a mathematical tool." According to our knowledge, energy is as real as anything else. As real as force. As real as speed. It essentially depends on what you mean by "real".

This has nothing to do with worldviews or energy. You are neglecting the interaction with the air. That gets you the wrong physics whatever techniques you use.

This site is about Physics, not Psychology.

"Since you believe in the law of conservation of energy, you must also believe in magic." Your question speaks for itself.

@MathKeepsMeBusy In the next sentence,  I immediately explained what the word magic means here.

@Justaphysicsstudent it is not magic that a falling object imparts energy to air molecules.

@MathKeepsMeBusy Did you not see "directly"?

@Justaphysicsstudent doesn't a falling object passing though air "directly" impart energy to air molecules?

@MathKeepsMeBusy I'll post another question on this topic and you can take a look at it then to see what I mean.

@Justaphysicsstudent sorry, I'm not interested.

@MathKeepsMeBusy It's okay, I understand, you are more interested in electrical engineering.

I am not going to dive much into the philosophical aspects of your question as I find such questions to be misplaced on this forum. However, I nevertheless want to just shortly mention that the question of whether something is a "real entity" firstly requires an underlying definition of realness. If e.g. energy is just a mathematical tool to describe our world, but still gives correct results, then it exists at least for us as a physical concept and is it then really any less real than any other quantities we use to describe the world?
Regarding the rest of your question: There is much more going on than you take into consideration. If you just neglect important aspects, then it is not surprising that your conclusion is inconsistent with established physical theory.
In more detail: In the absence any other forces than gravitation, your bamboo-copter will accelerate as predicted such that potential energy and kinetic energy are conserved. This has been tested experimentally (with at least a feather instead of a bamboo-copter). In the presence of air, the situation changes and energy will e.g. dissipate. This does not violate energy conservation as long as you take such additional forms of energy into account.
Surely, one cannot ultimately exclude that energy conservation does in fact not hold in our universe. But as long as the concept works and has not been falsified, I do not see any reason to not assume such a beautiful and useful concept to be true.

Your answer is great. I have added a few paragraphs to the question section, what do you think of them?

With the greatest respect, you are talking drivel. You are completely overlooking the fact that when an object falls on Earth it interacts with the atmosphere, losing energy to the air. Without such effects, parachutes would not work. If you were to release a bamboo-copter in a vacuum chamber, it would indeed accelerate all the way down.

You are not answering my questions. I think it's because you underestimated me. There is a reason why I chose the bamboo dragonfly instead of a parachute as an example.
I added a few paragraphs to the question section, you can take a look.

I answered your original question. Judging by the additions, I underestimated the depth of your confusion.

Specifically, what is my confusion?

You began your question by assuming that the PE of the copter must change into KE of the copter without loss, which is nonsense.

You then go on to suggest some magical process is required to explain what is happening. It is drivel.

No, my original question is irrelevant. But because it was closed for being too opinion-based, I am not allowed to post new posts until a week later.
Actually, I have prepared a thought experiment about a rusty-bearing bamboo dragonfly falling in a vacuum chamber and a normal bamboo dragonfly falling in air.
I suggest you read the new part I added which basically serves as a teaser
Looking forward to next week

Many thanks! I will look forward to it too. In the meantime, you must try to get out of the habit of posting irrelevant questions!!! Best wishes,
